# Parse radio button postback data using PHP

Tags: php

I have a question related to php. If anyone have an idea,please share with me. (I am a beginner in php).

I received a button value from an HTML page and displayed corresponding figure in the second page using code "param1.php". In the same program itself ( ie, "param1.php"), there is a set of radio box and i need to receive the radio value using another php program. But here i have confusion how to receive the radio value using another php program say "param2.php". also how the page redirect (to the php program where i receivvee the radio value) on selecting a radio button.

Thanks

I attach the "param1.php" below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<br>

<?php 
$data = $_POST['btn'];
$data2=$data.".png";
?>

<img src="<?php echo $data2;?>">

<h3>SCALE</h3>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="5,10,15" checked> 5,10,15<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="5,9,13"> 5,9,13<br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no form tags. Is your image named `4,9,13.png`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No form tags

There are no form tags, so your radio tags won't get `POST`'d to param2.php

```
<form action="param2.php" method="POST">
 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="5,10,15" checked> 5,10,15<br>
 <input type="radio" name="group1" value="5,9,13"> 5,9,13<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Process" />
</form>
```

#### Incorrect `$_POST` key

Now, in your `param2.php` file, you will be able to get the value of `POST['group1']`. In your code you're using the wrong key. `btn` doesn't exist within `$_POST` (in the code you've given anyway). The radio button name is `group1`, so access it as such;

```
$data = $_POST['group1'];
```

The value of `$data` will either be `4,10,15` or `5,9,13`. Ensure you've got an image named `4,9,13.png` and `4,10,15.png` else your image won't show. Because they're comma separated, I'm going to assume these are unique file names. So;

```
foreach( explode(",", $_POST['group1']) as $file) {
   echo "<img src='". $file .".png' />";
}
```

*Also, ensure you do some checks on the posted data to validate the user input*

Comment: You're welcome :) Please [mark the answer as accepted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) to notify others your question has been solved.